# what does v[2] means in terms of structure in c?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to understand the below program syntax with the structure.

```
struct virus
{
    char signature[25] ;
    char status[20] ;
    int size ;
} v[2] = {
    "Yankee Doodle", "Deadly", 1813,
    "Dark Avenger", "Killer", 1795
    };

main( )
{
    int i ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i <=1 ; i++ )
        printf ( "\n%s %s", v[i].signature, v[i].status ) ;
}
```

What does `v[2]` means here? I have never seen these kind of declarations before so bit of confuse over there. Can anyone explain me what does `v[2]` means here?

Comment: It's just declaring a length-2 array.

Comment: A variable named `v` is declared as an array of 2 values of type `struct virus`...

Comment: What does "I have never seen..." refer to exactly? You have never seen an array declaration, like `int a[2]`? Or you have never seen an array of structs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It makes `v` as array of `virus` structure with 2 elements and assigns values as defined in the rvalue.

Its similar to

```
struct virus
{
    char signature[25] ;
    char status[20] ;
    int size ;
};

struct virus v[2] = {
    "Yankee Doodle", "Deadly", 1813,
    "Dark Avenger", "Killer", 1795
};
```

Comment: To be pedantic, it's an array of `struct virus`.  (This makes a difference, because `virus` could in theory be a completely unrelated type, hence the `typedef struct T { ... } T;` idiom.)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct virus
{
    char signature[25];
    char status[20];
    int size;
} v[2] = /* ... */
```

It will define the identifier `v` as an array of 2 `struct virus`, initialized with the contents of the array initializer.

You can print its value to see what happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i;

for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    printf("%s %s %d\n", v[i].signature, v[i].status, v[i].size) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This declares an array of `struct virus` having and initializing two elements of the array.

The declaration coming before the `main( )` scope means the array will have global scope and static initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The array `v` is an array of two `struct virus`.  In the example the definition of `struct virus`, the array `v[]` and its initialisation are performed in one. The definition and declaration could be separated thus:

```
struct virus
{
    char signature[25] ;
    char status[20] ;
    int size ;
} ;

struct virus v[2] = { "Yankee Doodle", "Deadly", 1813,
                      "Dark Avenger", "Killer", 1795 } ;
```

Note also that strictly speaking the initializer in the example (and above) is mal-formed and should in fact be.

```
struct virus v[2] = { { "Yankee Doodle", "Deadly", 1813 },
                      { "Dark Avenger", "Killer", 1795  } } ;
```

I would expect a compiler to issue a warning in the first instance unless the warning level were set too rather low.